# Get-WMIObject failing in Task Sequence

Tags: powershell, sccm

I suppose this is more of a heads up than a question, but I welcome any criticism or wisdom.

I have been working on a PowerShell script which runs during a SCCM OSD Task Sequence. The purpose of the script is to move the computer into an AD Group depending on the Domain in which it is being built in. I noticed that the script would run fine during normal OS but would fail in the Task Sequence. I found that the Get-WmiObject commands were failing due to the cmdlets not being available.

This blog from [Mike Griswald](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/Mike+Griswold) helped shed some light: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/michaelgriswold/2015/07/27/powershell-failing-in-a-task-sequence/

Basically, once the OS has installed but the Task Sequence is still running, some of the fundamental PowerShell modules are not loaded. This includes the Microsoft.PowerShell.Management module which contains the Get-WmiObject cmdlets.
Here's the code I used:

```
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Management -Verbose
```

Mike suggests importing this module at the start of the script which does fix the problem. I think I interpret this as more of a workaround than a true solution because ideally I’d like to ensure all core modules are loaded as default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the blog post you quote it seems to be a feature of the SCCM OSD task sequence that PowerShell doesn't load all modules as such using Import-Module isn't so much a work around as the only way to perform the task.

The only other way I can think of to get what you want is to spawn another PowerShell process from the one in your task sequence. You could run a script that contained your WMI commands using the -File parameter as the new instance of PowerShell should have all modules available.  Please note this is just a thought - I don't have the environment to test it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try running a PSsession from a Management Server but that introduced different infrastructure based issues.